# Does chrome load videos in a different way than firefox?

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, video, html5

When trying to load videos onto a Three.js texture, I noticed that the Chrome is loading a video in ~2Mb chunks and playing the video once the chunk loads.

I am comparing this with firefox where a single GET request is shown. This request actually never fully resolves but the video loads smoothly on my texture.

One can see these results in the server I am working on if you open the dev tools and check out how heartBeatFullHD.mp4 loads:
https://blackfynnpythonlink.ml/hoverGraph/MPB/simple_heart/

Or alternatively, here are some photos displaying the requests being loaded:

## CHROME:[image: chrome video loading]

## FIREFOX:[image: firefox video loading]

Corresponding repo:
https://github.com/Tehsurfer/MPB

Comment: It appears to me you have answered your own question. Did you have another question than the one you asked and answered, perhaps?

Comment: Haha thank you. You're right, the answer is _*YES*_ ....

I was hoping someone might have some insight on how .mp4 files are loaded form a server in chrome and if there is a way to have some control over said loading.

Comment: Then please edit the question to make it more clear what you are actually asking.